# python math module, log10 in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to use log10 function in my list, however every time I have "a float is required error" even if i turn my list into float numbers. I don´t understand what I m doing wrong. This is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math
import operator

fileq= open("test.ppx1","r")
filer= open("test.prob1","r")
words = list(fileq.read().split())
words2 = list(filer.read().split())
words[:]=[x[:8] for x in words]
words2[:]=[x[:8] for x in words2]
id1= words[-1]
id2=words2[-1]
words.remove(id1)
words2.remove(id2)
map(float,words)
map(float,words2)


[math.log(y,10) for y in words]
[math.log(y,10) for y in words2]
```

This is the error i keep getting:

> TypeError: a float is required

Comment: Can you post example data or data format in test.ppx1 and test.prob1?

Comment: 2.506201e-08(this) 2.346253e-02(is) 1.282699e-02(a) 3.336181e-05(test) 1.821797e-07(this) 1.424501e-07(blablablabla:<UNK>) 1.515305e-01(</s>)  (utt-0000000001)

Comment: 2.506201e-08 2.346253e-02 1.282699e-02 3.336181e-05 1.821797e-07 1.424501e-07  utt-0000000001

Comment: The output of your map function is lost. In other words, the map function does not modify the list but returns a new one.

Comment: Your float values aren't getting stored anywhere. Try doing: `words = map(float, words)`

Answer (score 3):

```
map(float, words)
map(float, words2)
```

`map` isn't in-place. It returns a new list (in Python 2. In Python 3 it returns a `map object`). with the results of executing the function on the items of the given iterable.

Change these lines to:

```
words = map(float, words)
words2 = map(float, words2)
```